# How do I change the variable value in the inner class

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, local-variables, minesweeper

I am making a minesweeper game. I want to reduce the number of flags in the inner class but I get this error ."local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final java".How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a variable from the outer class in the inner class if it's not at least effectively final. An effectively final variable is a variable that is guaranteed to never change.

However, you **can** wrap your variable. Any kind or wrapper is good.
You can transform 'flags' (or whatever you called your variable) into one element array and use it instead:

```
final int[] flags = {0};
```

Now you can update your variable from the inner class:

```
flags[0]++;
```

You can also use `AtomicInteger` or any other kind of wrapper.

Comment: This is really bad advice and will fail once the code in the inner class is executed *after* the containing method is already done (think callbacks etc.).

Comment: No, I'm saying 'flags' should be his class variable. It shouldn't be declared inside the containing method.

Comment: Why are they closing my question? I asked an understandable question

Comment: Actually I have no idea...